# Implementing a memoization function in Haskell

Tags: haskell, memoization

I'm fairly new to Haskell, and I'm trying to implement a basic memoization function which uses a `Data.Map` to store computed values. My example is for Project Euler Problem 15, which involves computing the number of possible paths from 1 corner to the other in a 20x20 grid.

This is what I have so far. I haven't tried compiling yet because I know it won't compile. I'll explain below.

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map

main = print getProblem15Value

getProblem15Value :: Integer
getProblem15Value = getNumberOfPaths 20 20

getNumberOfPaths :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
getNumberOfPaths x y = memoize getNumberOfPaths' (x,y)
where getNumberOfPaths' mem (0,_) = 1
      getNumberOfPaths' mem (_,0) = 1
      getNumberOfPaths' mem (x,y) = (mem (x-1,y)) + (mem (x,y-1))

memoize :: ((a -> b) -> a -> b) -> a -> b
memoize func x = fst $ memoize' Map.Empty func x
    where memoize' map func' x' = case (Map.lookup x' map) of (Just y) -> (y, map)
                                                              Nothing -> (y', map'')
           where y' = func' mem x'
                 mem x'' = y''
                 (y'', map') = memoize' map func' x''
                 map'' = Map.insert x' y' map'
```

So basically, the way I have this structured is that `memoize` is a combinator (by my understanding). The memoization works because `memoize` provides a function (in this case `getNumberOfPaths'`) with a function to call (`mem`) for recursion, instead of having `getNumberOfPaths'` call itself, which would remove the memoization after the first iteration.

My implementation of `memoize` takes a function (in this case `getNumberOfPaths'`) and an initial value (in this case a tuple `(x,y)` representing the number of grid cell distances from the other corner of the grid). It calls `memoize'` which has the same structure, but includes an empty `Map` to hold values, and returns a tuple containing the return value and a new computed `Map`. `memoize'` does a map lookup and returns the value and the original map if there is a value present. If there is no value present, it returns the computed value and a new map.

This is where my algorithm breaks down. To compute the new value, I call `func'` (`getNumberOfPaths'`) with `mem` and `x'`. `mem` simply returns `y''`, where `y''` is contained in the result of calling `memoize'` again. `memoize'` also returns a new map, to which we then add the new value and use as the return value of `memoize'`.

The issue here is that the line `(y'', map') = memoize' map func' x''` should be under `mem` because it's dependent on `x''`, which is a parameter of `mem`. I can certainly do that, but then I will lose the `map'` value, which I need because it contains memoized values from intermediate computations. However, I don't want to introduce the `Map` into the return value of `mem` because then the function passed to `memoize` will have to handle the `Map`.

Sorry if that sounded confusing. A lot of this ultra-high-order functional stuff is confusing to me.

I'm sure that there is a way to do this. What I want is a generic `memoize` function that allows recursive calling exactly like in the definition of `getNumberOfPaths`, where the computation logic doesn't have to care exactly how the memoization is done.

Comment: I guess you may consider using a [map based memo monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-memo-0.4.1/docs/Control-Monad-Memo.html#g:4).

Comment: While that is a good solution, it is unlikely to be helpful to someone so new to Haskell and functional programming without a lot of explanation.

Comment: By the way, there is a *much* more efficient way to solve this problem that will completely eliminate the need for memoization. As in, so efficient you could probably do it by hand with pencil and paper in just a few minutes.

Comment: @Daniel I'm sure that's true, but I'd still like to have a generic memoization function for the future.

Answer (score 4):

Provided your inputs are small enough, one thing you can do is allocate the memo table as an `Array` instead of a `Map`, containing all the results ahead of time, but calculated lazily:

```
import Data.Array ((!), array)

numPaths :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
numPaths w h = get (w - 1) (h - 1)
  where

    table = array (0, w * h)
      [ (y * w + x, go x y)
      | y <- [0 .. h - 1]
      , x <- [0 .. w - 1]
      ]

    get x y = table ! fromInteger (y * w + x)

    go 0 _ = 1
    go _ 0 = 1
    go x y = get (x - 1) y + get x (y - 1)
```

You can also split this into separate functions if you prefer:

```
numPaths w h = withTable w h go (w - 1) (h - 1)
  where
    go mem 0 _ = 1
    go mem _ 0 = 1
    go mem x y = mem (x - 1) y + mem x (y - 1)

withTable w h f = f'
  where
    f' = f get
    get x y = table ! fromInteger (y * w + x)
    table = makeTable w h f'

makeTable w h f = array (0, w * h)
  [ (y * w + x, f x y)
  | y <- [0 .. w - 1]
  , x <- [0 .. h - 1]
  ]
```

And I won’t spoil it for you, but there’s also a non-recursive formula for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to implement `memoize :: ((a -> b) -> a -> b) -> a -> b`. In order to store the result for some `a` you're going to need a place in memory for that `a`, which means you're going to need to have some idea of what those `a`s are.

A ham-fisted approach would be to add a type-class for the types you know all the values of, like [`Universe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-1.0/docs/Data-Universe.html).

```
class Universe a where
    universe :: [a]
```

You could then implement `memoize :: (Ord a, Universe a) => ((a -> b) -> a -> b) -> a -> b` by building a `Map` that contains a `b` value for every `a` value in `universe :: [a]`, making the memoed function by passing the map lookup to the `func`, and populating the `b`s by declaring them to use the memoed function.

This won't work for `Integer` because there aren't a finite number of them. It won't even work for `Int` because there are too many of them. To memoize types like `Integer` you can use the approach used in [MemoTrie](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MemoTrie). Build a lazy infinite data structure that holds the values at the leaf.

Here's one possible structure for `Integer`s.

```
data IntegerTrie b = IntegerTrie {
    negative :: [b],
    zero :: b,
    positive :: [b]
}
```

A more efficient structure would allow for jumping deep into the trie to avoid exponential time lookup. For `Integers` MemoTrie takes the approach of converting the keys into lists of bits with some pair of function `a -> [Bool]` and `[Bool] -> a` and using approximately the following trie.

```
data BitsTrie b = BitsTrie {
    nil :: b,
    false :: BitsTrie b,
    true :: BitsTrie b
}
```

MemoTrie goes on to abstract over the types that have some associate trie that can be used to memoize them and provides ways to compose them together.

Comment: Is there no way to simply store the values as they are computed? I don't see why I should have to store all solutions for all inputs when the problem itself will know exactly which inputs it needs as it goes along.

Comment: Unless the structure that stores the values is independent of the steps the the problem takes as it goes along evaluating those steps has a side effect-mutating the structure that stores the values.

Comment: With a good memo trie the number of nodes that are ever constructed is proportional to the total size of the inputs that are evaluated.

Comment: The `memoize` package implements this.

Answer (score 1):

This might not directly help you implement memoization, but you can use someone else's... [monad-memo](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/monad-memo-0.4.1). Adapting one of their examples...

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Control.Monad.Memo

main = print $ startEvalMemo (getNumberOfPaths 20 20)

getNumberOfPaths :: (MonadMemo (Integer, Integer) Integer m) => Integer -> Integer -> m Integer
getNumberOfPaths 0 _ = return 1
getNumberOfPaths _ 0 = return 1
getNumberOfPaths x y = do
  n1 <- for2 memo getNumberOfPaths (x-1) y
  n2 <- for2 memo getNumberOfPaths x (y-1)
  return (n1 + n2)
```

... I suspect to implement something similar you can peek in their source https://github.com/EduardSergeev/monad-memo

Answer (score 1):

> What I want is a generic memoize function that allows recursive calling exactly like in the definition of getNumberOfPaths, where the computation logic doesn't have to care exactly how the memoization is done.

The State monad lends itself well to handling updates to a state, for example updates to a map of memoized values, without having to pass it around explicitly in the "business logic" part of the code, as the other answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/44492608/1319998 does.

In terms of separating the details of the memoization from the recursive function, you can hide the fact that a map, and even State, are being used behind a `type`. All the definition of the recursive function needs to know is that it must return a `MyMemo a b`, and instead of calling itself directly, it must pass itself and the next arguments to `myMemo`

```
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Control.Monad.State.Strict

main = print $ runMyMemo getNumberOfPaths (20, 20)

getNumberOfPaths :: (Integer, Integer) -> MyMemo (Integer, Integer) Integer
getNumberOfPaths (0, _) = return 1
getNumberOfPaths (_, 0) = return 1
getNumberOfPaths (x, y) = do
  n1 <- myMemo getNumberOfPaths (x-1,y)
  n2 <- myMemo getNumberOfPaths (x,y-1)
  return (n1 + n2)

-------

type MyMemo a b = State (Map.Map a b) b

myMemo :: Ord a => (a -> MyMemo a b) -> a -> MyMemo a b
myMemo f x = gets (Map.lookup x) >>= maybe y' return
  where
    y' = do
      y <- f x
      modify $ Map.insert x y
      return y

runMyMemo :: Ord a => (a -> MyMemo a b) -> a -> b
runMyMemo f x = evalState (f x) Map.empty
```

The above is essentially a roll-your-own version of https://stackoverflow.com/a/44478219/1319998 (well, rolling on top of State).

---

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/44515364/1319998 for suggestions on the code in `myMemo`

Answer (score 0):

> However, I don't want to introduce the Map into the return value of mem because then the function passed to memoize will have to handle the Map.

If I'm understanding, you will have to do *something* like this, at least if your aim is to store the memoized values in a map that gets copied on each new value found. Drawing attention to something that I don't think makes sense in terms of memoization...

```
getNumberOfPaths' mem (x,y) = (mem (x-1,y)) + (mem (x,y-1))
```

... means that any memoization from one branch `mem (x-1,y)`, can't be used in the other `mem (x,y-1)`, because the same `mem` will be used in both, containing the same information, whatevever value/function `mem` ends up being. You have to, somehow, pass memoized values from one to the other. This means the function called to recurse can't just return an `Integer`: it has to return an `Integer` along with some knowledge of the memoized values found along with that `Integer`.

There are a number of ways of doing this. Although perhaps undesirable due to the spread of the details of the memoization, you can pass the map about explicitly.

```
getNumberOfPaths :: (Integer, Integer) -> Integer
getNumberOfPaths (x, y) = snd $ memoize Map.empty getNumberOfPaths' (x, y) 

getNumberOfPaths' :: Map.Map (Integer, Integer) Integer -> (Integer, Integer) -> (Map.Map (Integer, Integer) Integer, Integer)
getNumberOfPaths' map (0,_) = (map, 1)
getNumberOfPaths' map (_,0) = (map, 1)
getNumberOfPaths' map (x,y) = (map'', first + second) where
  (map',   first) = memoize map  getNumberOfPaths' (x-1, y)
  (map'', second) = memoize map' getNumberOfPaths' (x, y-1)

memoize :: Ord a => Map.Map a b -> (Map.Map a b -> a -> (Map.Map a b, b)) -> a -> (Map.Map a b, b)
memoize map f x = case Map.lookup x map of
  (Just y) -> (map, y)
  Nothing  -> (map'', y) where
    (map', y) = f map x
    map''     = Map.insert x y map'
```

The `getNumberOfPaths'` does need to pass the map about, and needs to know it's signature, but at least it doesn't need to interact with the map: this is done in `memoize`, so I don't think it's *that* bad.

I think if you just wanted to be passing a function around, you can. You can use a chain of functions as a poor-man's map, but they do have to return a `Maybe`...

```
getNumberOfPaths :: (Integer, Integer) -> Integer
getNumberOfPaths (x, y) = snd $ memoize (const Nothing) getNumberOfPaths' (x, y) 

getNumberOfPaths' :: ((Integer, Integer) -> Maybe Integer) -> (Integer, Integer) -> ((Integer, Integer) -> Maybe Integer, Integer)
getNumberOfPaths' mem (0,_) = (mem, 1)
getNumberOfPaths' mem (_,0) = (mem, 1)
getNumberOfPaths' mem (x,y) = (mem'', first + second) where
  (mem',   first) = memoize mem  getNumberOfPaths' (x-1, y)
  (mem'', second) = memoize mem' getNumberOfPaths' (x, y-1)

memoize :: Eq a => (a -> Maybe b) -> ((a-> Maybe b) -> a -> ((a -> Maybe b), b)) -> a -> ((a -> Maybe b), b)
memoize mem f x = case mem x of
  (Just y) -> (mem, y)
  Nothing  -> (mem'', y) where
    (mem', y) = f mem x
    mem''     = \x' -> if x' == x then Just y else mem' x'
```

I wonder if you wanted to both a) use a map to store the values, and b) pass a function about as `mem`. However, I suspect this would be tricky, as, while you *can* pass a function that extracts from a map and return the extracted value, you can't then extract the map from this function to insert something into the map.

There is also the possibility of creating a monad for this (or using `State`). However, that may be left to another answer.